# Typescript: React render using external function which accepts component instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I'm creating a bunch of components with some common functions inside, one of them is the one that handles rendering. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
const render = (
    instance: React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => instance.state.flag ? cb() : '';

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() { return render(this, () => '') }
}
```

TypeScript, although, is not happy with this setup and says: `'render' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.` Personally, I can't see this reference.

As a possible clue, if I rewrite this code this way:

```
const render = (
    state: {flag: boolean},
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => state.flag ? cb() : '';

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() { return render(this.state, () => '') }
}
```

...all works well, but I really want to use the component itself, due to some complexities left out of sight for now.

What's the problem? Can I do something with this common function so that TypeScript doesn't argue?

---

**UPD:** a bit of testing let me created the example which is a bit more close to the one needed:

```
type Component<T> = React.Component<{}, {flag: T}>
const render = <T>(
    instance: Component<T>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => instance.state.flag ? cb() : '';

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() {
        const result = render(this, () => '');
        return result;
    }
    inner = () => 'test';
}
```

The main point here is the fact that external `render` function is generic, and `instance` type depends on the generic parameter, so that TypeScript is unable to substitute the proper parameter in place of `T`. Is it possible to help him without losing type-safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here seems to be with type inference of the instance argument in the render function.

Let's see

- Even if you mark the instance type as React.Component, when typescript try to infer render type it has to use 'this' instance that has to be React.Component<>, to do that it has to ckech render class member too, and back to start. So I suppose that typescript decide to give up about this inference

```
type RenderF = (
    instance: React.Component<any, any>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode) => React.ReactNode;

const render: RenderF = (
    instance: React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => instance.state.flag ? cb() : null;

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() { return render(this, () => null) }
}
```

- So an easy solution is to mark RenderF instance arguments as any, to avoid typescript inference to check the instance again.

```
type RenderF = (
    instance: any, // <-----
    cb: () => React.ReactNode) => React.ReactNode;

const render: RenderF = (
    instance: React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => instance.state.flag ? cb() : null;

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() { return render(this, () => null) }
}
```

**UPD**

If you don't want to loose type safety in instance argument you can specify only what you need in a new type

```
interface FlagComponent {
    state: { flag: boolean }
}

type RenderF = (
    instance: FlagComponent,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode) => React.ReactNode;

const render: RenderF = (
    instance: React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}>,
    cb: () => React.ReactNode
) => instance.state.flag ? cb() : null;

class Test extends React.Component<{}, {flag: boolean}> {
    state = {flag: true};
    render() { return render(this, () => null) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one worked. I'd add that this looks like work for `Pick<Component<T>, 'state'>` or something like that.